# Como chamar função javascript em asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Essa é minha função

```
<script>

    function keypressed(obj, e) {
        var tecla = (window.event) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        var texto = document.getElementById("numeros").value
        var indexvir = texto.indexOf(",")
        var indexpon = texto.indexOf(".")

        if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 0)
            return true;
        if (tecla != 44 && tecla != 46 && tecla < 48 || tecla > 57)
            return false;
        if (tecla == 44) { if (indexvir !== -1 || indexpon !== -1) { return false } }
        if (tecla == 46) { if (indexvir !== -1 || indexpon !== -1) { return false } }
    }

</script>
```

**Como eu posso chama-la no meu** `TextBox`?

Comment: Obs: eu consigo cham-la em uma pagina html desse modo:
<input type="text"id="numeros"value=""onkeypress="returnkeypressed( this , event );"/>
Mas não consigo chamá-la numa pagina asp.net. o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Esse ASP.NET é WebForms ou MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Você não chama ela no asp.net, asp.net é back-end. Você chama no html+javascript. No caso o script parece necessitar do `onkeydown` ao invés de `onkeypress`, mas como não sei o que o script faz, então não posso ter certeza, um exemplo para se usar seria:

```
<input type="text" id="numeros" value="" onkeydown="return keypressed( this , event );" />
```

Ou dentro de um arquivo javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
      //pega o seu input
      var numeros = document.getElementById("numeros");
      numeros.onkeydown = function(e) {
            keypressed(numeros, e)
      };
};
</script>
```

Comment: O meu script permite apenas a digitação de números e uma virgula. Em outro textbox eu chamei uma função dessa maneira: 
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalEstoque" runat="server" MaxLength="7"   onkeypress="return PermiteSomenteNumeros(event);"  Text='<%# Bind("TotalEstoque") %>'></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Por que não da certo com o outro script?

Comment: Não gerou nenhum erro não

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPreco" runat="server" class="txtPreco"; MaxLength="7" onkeypress="return keypressed( this , event );" Text='<%# Bind("Preco") %>'></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Essa função deveria permitir apenas a digitação de números e virgula, as isso não esta acontecendo.

Comment: Desculpa minha burrice, mas como eu mostro esse exemplo online?

Comment: Não, então pelo jeito não vai ter como

Comment: @Markim abre o navegador e na pagina aperta o Ctrl+U e copia o conteudo e cola no pastebin.com e manda o link aqui, assim eu posso analisar

Comment: Ah, nao consegui mexer no pastebin.com, mas obrigado pela atenção, amanhã eu tento resolver o erro

Answer (score 0):

Markin,

Complementando a resposta, no document.getElementById, você deve utilizar o ClientID. O Asp.net muda o nome em alguns casos quando envia para o Browser.

```
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "keypressed(obj, e)", "keypressed(obj, e)", True)
```

Editado: 
Vendo os comentários, e percebi que você quer montar uma mascára, não seria melhor usar alguma mascará pronta ? Exemplo: 
[JQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) 
[JQuery MoneyMask](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/)